# Displaying warnings generated by R script as they happen

Tags: r

I have a script that contains multiple blocks with lines that look like this...

```
#Read data for X
DataX = read.delim(file = 'XRecords.txt',
                   col.names = XFields[,'FieldName'])
print('Data X read')
#Convert fields that should be numeric into numeric so they can summed
DataX[,NumFieldNames] = as.numeric(as.character(XData[,NumFieldNames]))
print('Data X scrubbed')
```

When I source the script I get an output like this...

```
[1] "Data X read"
[1] "Data X scrubbed"
[1] "Data Y read"
[1] "Data Y scrubbed"
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Based on that output, I reload data Y and began looking for records where the string to numeric conversion failed. After a couple hours of frustration, I realized that data X was actually the one that had type conversion errors.

It looks like what's happening is that an warning is raised, but it does not display on the console until the script finishes. Is there a way to make warnings output to the console as soon as they are raised? I tried flush.console(), but it doesn't seem to work for warnings.

I'd prefer not to have load any additional packages onto my system if it can be avoided. I'm using this for work, and I had to jump through a few hoops just to get the CRAN distribution installed on my computer.

Thank you. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You'll have to pardon my (probably) loose vocabulary around R. I'm very new to the software.

Comment: Can you run the script interactively?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's make an example that shows the problem

```
foo <- function() {
  X <- c("1", "2", "three")
  print("Data X read")
  X <- as.numeric(X)
  print("Data X scrubbed")
  Y <- c("1", "2", "3")
  print("Data Y read")
  Y <- as.numeric(Y)
  print("Data Y scrubbed")
}
```

If run (even interactively), the behavior you see appears

```
> foo()
[1] "Data X read"
[1] "Data X scrubbed"
[1] "Data Y read"
[1] "Data Y scrubbed"
Warning message:
In foo() : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Behavior of warnings is handled with the `warn` option (see `help("options")`). That gives the choices including

> If `warn` is one, warnings are printed as they occur.

Changing the option to 1 then gives

```
> options(warn=1)
> foo()
[1] "Data X read"
Warning in foo() : NAs introduced by coercion
[1] "Data X scrubbed"
[1] "Data Y read"
[1] "Data Y scrubbed"
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that warnings in R are printed to stderr instead of stdout.  Flushing both stderr and out should solve the problem.

```
flush(stderr())
```

Comment: Is this really right? - - Can you have a more complete example?

Comment: The combo `flush(stderr())` and `flush(stdout())` did not work.  Neither did `flush.console()`.