# R Debugging - Cannot see which line generates warning message (Shiny)

Tags: r, debugging

Is there a way to make Rstudio tell you which line of which sourcefile generated a warning message?
Right now it just prints the message and I am lost as to what is causing the issue.

In Rstudio, this menu option is checked:
**Debug > Error > Error Inspector**

But it doesnt' help, probably because these are warnings and not errors? Ideas?

Comment: You can tell R to treat warnings as errors with `options(warn=2)`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde I ran that in the console and ran my shiny app again... so far, no difference. But thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind "errors" are different than "warnings." Using an error inspector won't do anything for warnings. Matthew's suggestion should have turned warnings into errors. If you didn't see a difference, that would be odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First turn on  [displaying warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439336/displaying-warnings-generate-by-r-script-as-they-happen) using the command
`options(warn=1)`
Then, you could run it by clicking on the "Source" or "Source with Echo" button (see image below). You can see the error/warning messages when any line with errors/warnings is executed.

[image]

Comment: I see. It's almost as if shiny::runApp() vs source() on the app.R file do different things... but yeah... source seems to bring back the 'show traceback' thing to help with debugging. This explains why sometimes I saw it and sometimes I didn't. Cos sometimes I would use source but most times I've just been using runApp(). Thanks!